# PostgreSQL: Filter for many values is slow

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance

I am surprised by the slow response time of a type of query and am hoping to get some advice.

Let's imagine a table `person` with the columns `id` (integer and primary key) and `age` (integer). I would like to compute the average age of a list of persons. I tried so far two queries:

Query 1:

```
select avg(p.age)
from persons p
where p.id = any(...);
```

Query 2:

```
select avg(p.age)
from
  (values
    (1),
    (2),
    ...
  ) as i (id)
  join person p on i.id = p.id;
```

For a large number of IDs, e.g., 2 million, the queries are both surprisingly slow (in my setup it takes >10s) with query 1 being slower than query 2. If the IDs were already in a database table and we were doing a normal join of two existing tables, it is fast.

I don't understand why it is so slow and how/whether it can be improved. As `id` is the primary key, there is obviously an index on it.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add both [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Also, please specify the database version..